# Public Datasets on Azure Data Lake Store to use with Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

Does Azure Data Lake store Public Datasets to use with Azure Data Lake Analytics? Google BigQuery provides public datasets, something similar to that, so that it would be easy to create tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out.  Today we don't yet have broadly available public data-sets.  This is something that we are working on, but I don't have a timeframe that I can share.

Thank you,
Guy